# Evaluation of this integral: $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}axe^{-\frac 1 2 ax^2}\big[ax^2-3\big]dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am looking for some help in evaluating the following integral. I am not asking you to do it for me! 
\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}axe^{-\frac 1 2 ax^2}\bigg[ax^2-3\bigg]dx
\end{equation}
I let $u=ax^2$,
\begin{equation}
\frac 12 \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac 12 u}\bigg[u-3\bigg]du
\end{equation}
Yet from here I am quite stuck!

Comment: Hint: Integration by parts.

Comment: Take care : $u=ax^{2}$ then $0\leq u\leq+\infty$ (I assume that $a$ is non-negative for convergence). To compute your integral, split it into two parts and do some integrations by part (they are not difficult at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may notice that
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}axe^{-\frac 1 2 ax^2}\bigg[ax^2-3\bigg]dx=0$$ since the integrand is an odd function.

Comment: That's very elegant but how did you know the parity at first glance?

Comment: @Gonate Because the integrand is of the form $x \times f(x^2)$, the integral being convergent over the symetric interval. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you also verify that the integral exists? Because of the exponential, intuitively, I'd say it exists if $a>0$, but I'm not so sure it does if $a<0$

Comment: @BernardMassé You are right, I've assumed here that $a>0$, otherwise the integral is divergent.

Comment: In the question $a>0$. Thanks guys!